# Can't get my htaccess to work on a 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I’m trying to redirect an https://www.domain.ext to a plain https://domain.ext, but just can’t get it to work; this is where I’m right now:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https\:\/\/www\.cadenanoticias\.mx$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/cadenanoticias\.mx" [R=301,L]
```

Allso tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} *!^https\://www*.cadenanoticias\.mx [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://cadenanoticias.mx/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And not working see: https:www.cadenanoticias.mx
Any idea on why it’s not working?

UPDATE FIX

Got it to work as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cadenanoticias\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cadenanoticias.mx/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.cadenanoticias\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` does not match against protocol. Use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cadenanoticias\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cadenanoticias.mx/$1 [R=301,L]
```

***EDIT** :*
No, bypassing the SSL certificate validation is not possible. The SSL handshake precedes `htaccess` rules for security reasons. If this was possible, a hacker could hijack a SSL connection to an insecure one without really needing a valid certificate.

There's no solution for this other than buying a cheaper certificate just to do handshake and redirect.

Comment: I just tried and it worked for me. Although the browser did prompt me about invalid security certificate.

Comment: exactly, That’s precisely what I don’t want, I want it to bypass immediately to https\://mydomain.mx

Comment: Definitely, going for a another SSL. Thank you